# Github markdown render is not equivalent to VS Code

Tags: markdown

I have a section of Latex that is written as,

```
1. First she must calculate the inverse of $e \ (d)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{1440}$. Recall that $e$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ if $e$ * $e^{-1} \equiv 1 \ mod \ n$. This is easily done using Euclidian's algorithm. <br>
```

In VS Code this renders correctly and displays

[image]

However in Github it displays,

[image]

From what I have experienced Github has minor tweeks to what it does and does not support, but what can I do here to display what I have in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix to this is to escape your underscore characters, as they are currently being interpreted as italics instead of as part of the mathematical equation:

```
1. First she must calculate the inverse of $e \ (d)$ in $\mathbb{Z}\_{1440}$. Recall that $e$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}\_{n}$ if $e$ * $e^{-1} \equiv 1 \ mod \ n$. This is easily done using Euclidian's algorithm. <br>
```

Example of this rendered in the GitHub markdown editor:

[image: rendered markdown]